# 2D array elements not being read properly

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, io

The output is a string of numbers of entire row/column instead of a single number. Can someone please help me in this?

```
int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    int n,m,cnt=0;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<=n+1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=m+1;j++){
            if(i==0||i==n+1||j==m+1||j==0) G[i][j]=0;
            cin>>G[i][j];
        }
    }
 cout<<G[1][2]<<endl;//this gives wrong o/p
```

return 0;
}

Comment: What is the code language?

Comment: @STF the coding language used is c++.

Comment: I doubt this code can even just works, the curly bracket that closes the while loop is missing.

Comment: this is just a snippet from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are reading out of bounds due to a `i <= n + 1` and `j <= m + 1` conditions in your `for` loops thus invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) resulting in a corrupted stack which explains the output you are seeing. Modify the boundaries to:
`i < n` and `j < m`. Arrays are zero indexed in C++. First array element is accessed via `somearray[0]` and the last element is `somearray[n-1]` not `somearray[n]` which is what you are trying to access in your code. The same goes for multi-dimensional arrays. The statement of:

```
cout << G[i][j] << endl;
```

is wrongly placed outside the `for` loops. It should be inside the inner `for` loop. The array should be defined as a second statement in your `while` loop:

```
int G[n][m]; // Avoid VLAs
```

That being said variable length arrays are not part of the C++ standard and you  should prefer `std::vector` and `std::array` to raw arrays.

Comment: it is a global array A[101][101] and i am trying to pad zeroes around the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `G` is a 2D array of size `n x m`, then you go out of bounds here:

```
for(int i=0;i<=n+1;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<=m+1;j++)
```

since array indexing starts from 0, and ends at size - 1.

As a result, your code invokes Undefined Behavior. To avoid that, simply change your double for loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < m; j++)
```